# CSS Center Image Horizontally Inline Dynamic Width Parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center an image horizontally inside of a `div` that has a width of `100%`. Currently I have two images on either side that will act as buttons that have a `float: left;` and `float: right;` property.

All of the solutions I have tried have said to make the image `display: block` but that won't allow me to have the buttons on either side.

Here is the [Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/fishcharlie/pen/rrAAYX) of my current code. I'm trying to center the image that has the class `mainimg` within the div with the class `main`.

Any ideas of how I would center that image?

Comment: put your floats FIRST: `<div><floatleft><floatright><centeredimage></div>`, basically.

Comment: If the left and right elements aren't the same width you will need to use absolute positioning.

Comment: @MarcB Not sure exactly how that would help. How would that centered image know to get centered at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flexbox and change your CSS rule for `.main` like this:

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: black;
  height: 550px;
}
```

`display: flex;` will distribute the three items across the width, `justify-content: space-between;` will make sure the outer items remain at the outside positions.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkjjJa

Comment: Note this only centers the middle items if the left and right elements **are the same size**.

Comment: yes, but it was obvious that this is the case here (identical arrow images).